# Facebook Graph API - comments missing from data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a web app that'll read the contents of a Facebook page. It's currently accessing all the posts and those comments made by the page but there is a problem with comments added by others

For example, If I write a post as the page, and then add a comment as they page - all appears fine. But then if I add a comment as an individual, whilst the text of the comment comes through, the 'from' information (id, name) does not.

This is an example of the call I'm making:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID_POSTID?access_token=PAGEACCESSTOKEN
```

And this is a subset of the response:

```
"comments": {
  "data": [
     {
        "id": "PAGEID_POSTID_COMMENTID",
        "from": null,
        "message": "Testing adding a comment",
        "created_time": "2012-07-06T19:27:08+0000"
     }
  ]
```

I'm expecting "from" to contain the ID and name of the poster (as it does when I'm adding a comment as the page).

I can also try and grab the comments out based on the PAGE_POST_COMMENT ID, but in this case the response is **false**. Unless I pass the access token of the user adding the comment then it works fine (which I won't have in the vast majority of cases).

The user adding the comment has the default privacy settings (public) so that doesn't seem to be an issue.

I can kinda understand that this is an authentication issue - but I'm not sure why it's preventing me from seeing who's posted on the comments. It's little use showing me the comment unless I know who it's from!

Permissions wise, the app has 'manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream'.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Cheers,
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with Facebook test users system. I get the problem above when adding a comment as a test user, but if I try it on a live page with a live user it works fine!

I've raised a bug with Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331098286974765